# Moxy. Android. MVP. Реализация в BasePresenter

Tags: android, kotlin, mvp, moxy

Разбирался как устроен Moxy. И возникла некая проблема. Любой presenter наследуется от BasePresenter (также и с View, также имеется BaseView). В примере, MainPresenter наследуется от BasePresenter, поэтому наследоваться от MvpPresenter не получается (уже есть один super type). Остается вариант с BasePresenter, но там выдает ошибку (ошибка представлена ниже). Также происходит ошибка и со View. Как лучше поступить в данном случае. Избавиться от BasePresenter и BaseView? Но это придется код каждый раз копировать (не все было вставлено в эти классы, вставил только, что считал необходимым). Да, и в MainActivity имеется @InjectPresenter, но не в нем дело.

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity<MainPresenter>(), MainView {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        presenter.pushFragments(
            Const.TAG_ENTRANCE,
            EntranceApp(),
            supportFragmentManager
        )
    }
}

override fun instantiatePresenter(): MainPresenter {
    return MainPresenter(mainView = this)
} }
```

BaseActivity.kt

```
abstract class BaseActivity<Presenter> : BaseView, MvpAppCompatActivity() {

     protected val presenter: Presenter by lazy { instantiatePresenter() }

     protected abstract fun instantiatePresenter(): Presenter

     override fun getContext(): Activity = this }
```

MainPresenter.kt

```
class MainPresenter(mainView: MainView) : BasePresenter<MainView>(mainView) {}
```

BasePresenter.kt

```
@InjectViewState
abstract class BasePresenter<V : BaseView>(protected val view: V): MvpPresenter<V>() {
private val injector: PresenterInjector = DaggerPresenterInjector
    .builder()
    .baseView(view)
    .contextModule(ContextModule)
    .networkModule(NetworkModule)
    .databaseModule(DatabaseModule(view.getContext()))
    .build()

init {
    inject()
}

private fun inject() {
    when (this) {
        is SplashPresenter -> injector.inject(this)
    }
} }
```

MainView.kt и BaseView.kt

```
interface BaseView: MvpView {
    fun getContext(): Context
}

interface MainView: BaseView
```

Ошибка в BasePresenter

```
Moxy compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View "" for com.viground.ui.base.BasePresenter cannot be found)
```

Comment: @InjectViewState должно быть над наследниками, не на абстрактном классе

Answer (score 2):

Аннотация `@InjectViewState` позволяет сгенерировать для вашего `Presenter-а` объект `ViewState`. `MvpPresenter` создает экземпляр этого `ViewState`, и кладет его себе в качестве поля и будет везде использовать его. Вам же просто останется работать с методом `public View getViewState()` из `MvpPresenter`.

Из этого следует, что применять аннотацию можно только к конкретным классам `Presenter-а`. В вашем же случае вы пытаетесь применить ее к абстрактному классу.

Comment: спасибо, да, я разобрался и переделал немного. Проблема вся была в том, как правильно встроить и dagger, и moxy. Помогла вот эта статья (взял необходимое) https://dajver.blogspot.com/2017/08/dagger-2-retrofit.html (очень хорошая показалась мне), ну и сама документация https://github.com/moxy-community/Moxy. Сложил вместе, и получилось недурно, вроде бы как)